# BRAM memory in FPGA

Tags: fpga, memory, bram

Can someone explain how a Block RAM in FPGA works?
I was creating a memory for 128k and could not figure out how would I create a memory module for it.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to create block RAM in FPGAs.  One is explicit instantiation, where you instantiate a block RAM primitive.  The other is implicit instantiation, where you write HDL code that behaves like a memory and then the synthesizer infers a block RAM (or multiple block RAMs) with the required characteristics.  If your synthesizer is smart enough, I highly recommend using inferred memories.  They are more portable (not tied to a specific chip or toolchain) and they are usually easier to parametrize and debug.

Can you provide some more information on what language, toolchain, and chip you are using?